# Have the Talosians helped other hopelessly injured Federation members?

Tags: star-trek

The kindness the Talosians showed to Pike and Vina would be extremely valuable for other hopelessly injured people. Was what they did for Pike and Vina done out of a sense of obligation or altruism plus enlightened self-interest: they found Pike an especially interesting person due to his experiences as a starship captain.

If Pike was especially interesting, perhaps some novel (I am aware of no mention in a movie or episode) has members of various species who need the sort of help the Talosians can provide applying to live on Talos -- perhaps for a completely realistic experience one has to live physically on Talos, perhaps because the Talosians have the technology to support completely paralyzed people.

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/General_Order_7 - "*No vessel under any condition, emergency or otherwise, is to visit Talos IV.*" - https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/memoryalpha/images/a/a9/Talos_IV_%28file%29_content.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/1000?cb=20050113015119&path-prefix=en

Comment: +1 It does seem that the title "The Menagerie" could imply 'A collection of wild or exotic animals…'—1913 Webster.

Answer (score 1):

No. The Talosians asked to not be visited after the Enterprise came by, and in "The Menagerie", travelling to the planet, and violating the rule against travelling there is one of the few regulations that still has a death penalty.

Vina was unable to live a normal life outside of Talos IV, since the Talosians botched her reconstruction, so she was allowed to live there, and Pike was returned there after special exception, after an accident similarly robbed him of his ability to live his life.

The Talosians refused to leave their planet, or give the Federation their technology, fearing that the Federation would come to ruin as they did. The Federation turning their planet into a dumping ground for the infirm would not be ethical.

In Discovery, we also know that the Talosians now hide the planet under the guise of a black hole, and since the Federation has no way to contact the Talosians, they would have no way send anyone there.